# git remote refs are not displayed when origin is a cifs mount on linux

Tags: linux, git, devops

I have a git repo on windows file share and I need to access it on Linux machine.

The share is mounted on Linux machine with cifs. I have set the remote as origin giving path to the cifs mount point.

```bash
user@server1[/tmp/local-source]$ df -Th | grep win-share
//winserver/some-git-folder                       cifs      670G  612G   59G  92% /tmp/win-share
```

```bash
user@server1[/tmp/local-source]$ git remote -v
origin  /tmp/win-share (fetch)
origin  /tmp/win-share (push)
```

```bash
user@server1[/tmp/local-source]$ git ls-remote origin "refs/merge-requests/*"
user@server1[/tmp/local-source]$
```

…while on the windows server on the git folder I can see those refs.

```bash
$ git ls-remote origin "refs/merge-requests/*/merge" | tail
01119bfefbcbf63ec1b52e65b2f0e549dfce920e        refs/merge-requests/7972/merge
fa616411b7357afee92169f2f29b8b7c61b8f075        refs/merge-requests/7973/merge
ea32657d7ac703349fde8e1b37516258be578a9e        refs/merge-requests/7974/merge
6253457c1d65914e419bf252954357cde813c6f4        refs/merge-requests/7975/merge
19459ba751bad54dd6d1e87534b788038c07f0f5        refs/merge-requests/7976/merge
d7c369199584063c4879ec3d1f72778e60343ebc        refs/merge-requests/7977/merge
08bb7ea033cf41d371629d5a85135d1e9c66998c        refs/merge-requests/7978/merge
b3381b601295767fd1ac38b6c99154df6baaf741        refs/merge-requests/7979/merge
f1f2e70139b0941c5d127becc1801e007654be9d        refs/merge-requests/7980/merge
56785811fe09e7dac89df949b13af359ff681df9        refs/merge-requests/7981/merge
```

Is there anything else I need to check ?

I tried adding `GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM=1` as env variable.

Comment: Can you make a copy of `/tmp/win-share` to `/tmp/copy-share`, and test again ?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there anything else I need to check ?

You're not showing what your server has configured as `origin`, it's a repo-local name the factory defaults set up as the repo they cloned from.

Your `local-source` repo cloned from your `win-share` repo, so `git clone` set up an `origin` remote pointing to that `win-share` repo.

But the windows server was cloned from somewhere, and wherever that is, that's its `origin`.

When you clone, you get a new repository with, by default, all its origin's  branches and tags and the `HEAD`, the current checkout, but you get nothing else.

There are a lot of refs used for in-flight administration, the default is to *not* clone those. And the new clone's configuration is entirely up to you, nothing of that is copied from the origin, it's set up fresh from whatever template you use.